# Connection error when running docker commands

Tags: docker

On running `docker images`, I am getting error

```
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/images/json:
open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be
run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker
daemon is not running.
```

I am on Windows 10 Home and have tried to install/reinstall Docker but I keep getting the error. Things were working fine an hour back!

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you have a VM running under `docker-machine`? You can run the below command:

```
docker-machine ls
```

And if you haven't installed docker-machine, please install it.

> Ref:- https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/

***Note***:- Make sure enabled the BIOS virtualization.